# Null Object Reference with setters and getters SAXParser Android

Tags: java, android, rss, nullreferenceexception, saxparser

I keep getting a null object reference with the setter in Android. Here is the trace:

04-04 09:18:15.465 32664-1342/com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp I/XMLHelper: TAG: rss 04-04 09:18:15.465 32664-1342/com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp I/XMLHelper: TAG: channel 04-04 09:18:15.465 32664-1342/com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp I/XMLHelper: TAG: link 04-04 09:18:15.465 32664-1342/com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp I/XMLHelper: TAG: title 04-04 09:18:15.475 32664-1342/com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp E/XMLHelper: Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.farhad.rssfeedfyp.TPostValue.setTitle(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

the source code is available on https://github.com/farhadmiah/RssFeedFyp. would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 99 in your XML helper you only create a new item object if the element's name is `item`.

Then in `endElement(...)`, you set the title if the name is `title`.
So you encountered a `title` element which is not inside an `item` element, before creating the first item.

You should probably add an extra check if `item` is not null.
Also null the `item` out to avoid unexpected data.